# MODIS images calibration

Tags: qgis, modis

I'm working with MODIS (MOD09GA Collection 6.1) images. Do they need to be calibrated to use them correctly in calculating biophysical indices (NDVI...)?
[Downloaded from this website](https://search.earthdata.nasa.gov/search/granules/collection-details?p=C2202497474-LPCLOUD&q=modis)

Comment: @MrXsquared Yes, I reposted it, because no one answered me

Comment: @MrXsquared Ohh, I didn't know that, thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MOD09GA (and MYD09GA) products contain surface reflectance (already corrected for atmospheric effects), but you will likely find quite a lot of BRDF variation in the signal, even when calculating a vegetation index. You should also inspect the QA layer to check for missing data, clouds, etc (see https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/products/mod09gav061/ for links to more resources, including [the user's guide](https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/documents/925/MOD09_User_Guide_V61.pdf).)

Comment: Thank you so much